# Don't effect element position while scaling stage in konva.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs, konva

I am creating page creation software online using amazing konva.js so the problem is when I was scaling the stage the whole elements are changing there position. Before scaling whole stage
[image]

After scaling the stage the line text is not in center.

[image]

the background at back is just rect having same width height of stage and having background image.

This is my scaling code.

```
function scaleboth(_x,_y){
stageBackgroundRect.scale({x:_x,y:_y});
stage.scale({x:_x,y:_y});

layer.batchDraw();
}
```

if you want to see demo here it is,
https://mypagemaker.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html
Thanks, I promise I will give bounty to correct answer.

As I have to offset it,I have done this but no change

```
function minusStage(){
    stage.offsetX(stage.width() / 2);
    stage.offsetY(stage.height() / 2);

    scaleboth(stage.scaleX() - 0.01,stage.scaleY() - 0.01);
}
```

Comment: There is a good demo on zooming / scaling relative to a point here https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Zooming_Relative_To_Pointer.html

Comment: Scaling is applied from the top-left corner of the stage. If you wanted to scale from the center you have to offset the stage as part of your scaling code before the draw.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat there is change but as you can see the `stage.width() / 2` is not giving proper center. I also added padding to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background rectangle is inside a stage. So scaling the stage will affect the absolute scaling of all its children including the background rectangle.

You just need to apply scale once on one of the parents (it can be the stage).

Comment: 100% right, I have figured it out before by randomizing my code means just comment some code and try to run other (you know very well) but I forget to post it here